# photo properties in facebook

Tags: facebook

Does facebook always remove photo properties after it is uploaded in their site? Is there any way to preserve the photo properties even though it is uploaded. Is there a method to retrieve the photo properties of the photos that are uploaded to facebook?

Comment: Are you talking about EXIF data? It looks like no to all those. Facebook uses a pretty aggressive compression algorithm for both space and privacy that strips all extraneous data.

Answer (score 0):

With FQL you can retrieve the info...

Take a look at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/